# ManyToOne form creating linked object

Tags: doctrine, symfony

Imagine these 2 entities:

```
Article
  title
  description
  category <- ManyToOne

Category
  name
```

Say we need to manage an article with a form and the category attached.

```php
$builder
    ->add('name')
    ->add('description')
    ->add('category')
```

This one will allow me to select from existing categories.

Now I'd like to be able to create categories if needed.

```
Title    [                 ]
Description
[                          ]
[                          ]
Category [                 ]
```

The category field would be a free text box.
If the text corresponds to no category, a new one would be created and attached.
I tried with some `DataTransformer` with no luck

I need a reusable solution to manage that because I'll need to embed it especially in another form as a collection.

How can I do it reusable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I ended up with using a [`DataTransformer`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html)

My `ArticleType`:

```php
class ArticleType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('description')
            ->add('category', CategoryType::class)
//...
```

A new `CategoryType` class:

```php
class CategoryType extends AbstractType
{
    protected $myService;

    public function __construct(MyService $myService)
    {
        $this->myService = $myService;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $transformer = new CategoryTransformer($this->myService);
        $builder->addModelTransformer($transformer);
    }
}
```

Registered as service

```yml
app.form.category_type:
    class: AppBundle\Form\CategoryType
    arguments: ['@app.my.service']
    tags:
        - { name: form.type }
```

And finally the transformer:

```php
class CategoryTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{
    // ...MyService initialization...

    public function transform($category)
    {
        if (null === $category) {
            return '';
        }
        return $category->getName();
    }

    public function reverseTransform($categoryName)
    {
        if (!$categoryName) {
            return null;
        }
        $category = $this->myService->getOrCreateCategoryFromName($categoryName);

        if (null === $category) {
            throw new TransformationFailedException();
        }

        return $category;
    }
}
```

`MyService` is responsible to get or create a category with the given name using the entity manager.

Quite some lines of code but once this is done, wherever I'll use my form, it can be dealt in the easy standard way:

```php
$articleForm = $this->createForm(ArticleType::class, $article);
$articleForm->handleRequest($request);

if ($articleForm->isValid()) {
    $em->persist($article);
    $em->flush();
//...
```

Comment: Actually this does not work with collections, in the case we enter more than one `Article` with the same new `Category`

Answer (score 0):

Suggest that you do an "if" on your category.
When you check your form submission is valid and submitted, get the 'category' data, and if not exists persist it as a new category then query for the article after.

The code might be something like this:

```
if ($form-isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){
    $catName = $form->get('category')->getData();   // Get category.

    // Query if it exists.
    $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->select('c')
        ->from('AppBundle:Category', 'c')
        ->where('c.name = :catName')
        ->setParameter('catName', $catName);
    $cat_results = $qb->getQuery()->setMaxResults(1)->getOneOrNullResult();

    if ($cat_results == null){
        $newCat = new Category();
        $newCat()->setname($catName);
        $em->persist($newCat);
        $em->flush();
    }
    else{
        ...
        \\ Render your form etc...
    }
```

Hopefully you get the idea. The above code is simpler, because then you create the category in the same form.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I forgot to mention I'm searching for a reusable solution maybe involving a `DataTransformer` or something. Because I'll be using this in several of my controllers